# Markup in comments?

Tags: 2013, markup

I've searched without any luck.  I'm commenting on a discussion on our sharepoint site and want to add some simple markup.  Perhaps a link with a label or some bold text.  Is this possible?  I've tried standard wiki markup and even bbcode in desperation :)

Comment: ahh, so whoever set it up probably didn't do that...  neat.

Comment: If your question is answered, you probably delete it or ask the commentator to write it as an answer to close the question.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comments box needs to be a rich text field. It can be set like that in the list setting for that column.